# Prevent user input to oversize PHP "allowed memory size"

Tags: php

I'm getting some variables with $_POST, mainly inputted by the user on a form.
To prevent huge values to be inserted in the form, I can check those variables and return an error to the user if they're to long.

However, I can't do that if the user input a REALLY long value because, in this case, the entire script crash before I can even refuse to process that variable. Is this a threat to the security of my server?

How can I fix this without increasing the default memory limit? Is it possible?

Restraining user input with a javascript could be an option, but the user may easily overcome that limit by disabling javascript.

Comment: what about the `MAXLENGTH` parameter for input fields? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp

Comment: How can it be a treat because the script does not even run? If people are doing this to your web site they are trying a deny service attack.

Comment: @Saturnix - Assume you can get crap from the users side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the maximum size of a post body using the ini directive `post_max_size`. However its defaults to 8M. If it is unchanged it should be ok as the default `memory_limit` is 128M. (php 5.3)

But of course this depends on what you are about to do with the data and how much memory PHP will consume for this. In extreme speak, it would be even possible to create an example script that reaches the memory limit with a 1 byte input. So you'll have to find the proper value for your application.

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

> Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than upload_max_filesize. If memory limit is enabled by your configure script, memory_limit also affects file uploading. Generally speaking, memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size. When an integer is used, the value is measured in bytes. Shorthand notation, as described in this FAQ, may also be used. If the size of post data is greater than post_max_size, the $_POST and $_FILES superglobals are empty. This can be tracked in various ways, e.g. by passing the $_GET variable to the script processing the data, i.e. , and then checking if $_GET['processed'] is set.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to php.ini? You can set upload_max_filesize / post_max_size

See here for details: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads

(p.s. setting maxlength in the HTML form is easily circumvented by a malicious user)

Answer (score 0):

Divides the data on the client into parts and download in parts via Ajax, then save the downloaded part on the disc or in the database. Maybe this way?